# Cannot get an Excel file to open - Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: excel, pandas, matplotlib

I am a beginner to programming, and just started learning Python myself for work.

My objective is to plot two variables on a simple xy chart. I have an Excel file (also saved in .csv) with list of outlets, turnover, and expenses. I want to plot turnover on the x-axis and expenses on the y-axis.

I combed through some articles, and all of them mention that it is the easiest thing to do, so I am using the following code (matplotlib and pandas have been installed):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\PS\Desktop\Data.xlsx")
plt.plot(df['Turnover'], df['Expenses'])
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, I cannot even get the file to open. The errors I am receiving are as follows.
Could someone guide me, please?
Thank you so much in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PS/PycharmProjects/Test1/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\PS\PycharmProjects\Test1\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\PS\PycharmProjects\Test1\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Is ft2font installed, maybe try pip install ft2font

Comment: Hello, I am using PyCharm, and it doesn't seem to recognise ft2font. Is that the correct spelling?

Answer (score 0):

After reading csv Try this,

```
x = df["Turnover"].values  

y = df["Expenses"].values

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am still getting the exact same error. I thought it was a problem with installation, but I received notifications that said matplotlib and pandas were successfully installed.

Comment: It may be a problem with matplotlib  import (you may get some error like due to circular import) so go to your folder location    C:\Users\PS\PycharmProjects\Test1\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib      and find " __init__.py " and delete it, and then run our code.